# What is the standard for sharing/transferring databases?

Tags: sql, database, standards

Im a beginner in database management and want to know what is the standard procedure of sharing databases? Im a self taught person and would like to know how things work. For reference, I have hired someone to build a database for me on sql and have also told him the logic and relationships between different variables but i need him to give the database to me completely so that he does not have the access to it anymore. How to go about it? What's the standard practice? I have looked online and for most of people use github but im kind of confused about it. would appreciate the help, thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, here is what my understanding is so far:

I can ask the developer to create a backup and export the sql dump file to me along with the schema and documentation. This way I can import the file and change the login credentials. Is this the right procedure?

Comment: SQL is pretty much the standard. However, some vendors provide dedicated binary format that may offer better performance. Or you can just grant access to an online server and revoke credentials when no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it really depends on who you're asking.

In our company, we make daily database backups (as SQL files) and store them on a dedicated server so we can import them whenever needed.
However, if you just want the structure of the database without the data you could also save the SQL´s used to a file and share it on your git repo.

We also have something like current_sqls.sql file which contains every SQL we used so if for some reason we have a problem we can also get back to the latest structure at least.

In your problem, I guess the easiest way for him would be just to export the database and send it to you so you can import it.